# Can all proven theorems be proven by contradiction?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-theory

The answers to the question [Can every true theorem that has a proof be proven by contradiction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081396/can-every-true-theorem-that-has-a-proof-be-proven-by-contradiction) show that if a theorem can be proven directly, it can be proven by contradiction.

The main arguments presented there are of the form:

> Let P be a proof of the theorem. Assume the theorem is false. However
>   we can exhibit P, which contradicts the assumption

However this argument assumes that we can rely on the validity of the direct proof in our proof by contradiction.

My question is then, if you have a theorem that can be proven directly, is it possible to prove the theorem by contradiction, **but without using the fact that there exists a direct proof in your proof by contradiction**?

Comment: Yes, assume not $P$, then prove $P$, and you have a contradiction to not $P$, thus proving not not $P$.

Comment: That's a question that does not seem to be easy to formalize. What's the motivation for it ? (If there is any, besides curiosity, which is a valid reason for asking of course)

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, yes but the bold of my question states you cannot use the direct proof in your argument.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : look at the specific question, which is asking if we can do it "without using a proof of $P$"

Comment: I think the answer is no. Remember that Godell already said that some theorems are not even probable by the maths we have. So in order to prove that those theorems are true the only possible thing we can do is prove that they are unprovable. Otherwise, they would have a counterexample which we could find.

Comment: @ErikT., to be clear, I'm only referring to the theorems that can already be proven directly.

Comment: If you prove a theorem then do you really **use** the fact that a direct proof exists? It is more that you **show** or **confirm** that a direct proof exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not necessarily -- but for even less interesting reasons than the argument you don't like!

The following is fact:

> First-order Peano Arithmetic proves $\forall x\forall y( x\cdot Sy = x\cdot y + x )$.

The proof is very simple -- since the claim to be proved is one of the axioms of PA, simply stating it with "(axiom)" next to it constitutes a proof.

On the other hand, the *other* axioms of PA are not sufficient to prove the claim -- to see this, observe that we get a model of those other axioms by taking the universe to be $\mathbb N$, $S$ to be the successor function, $+$ to be addition, and $\cdot$ to be the constant function that always returns $0$. This model does not satisfy the claim we want to prove, so since first-order logic is sound, the claim does not have a proof.

In other words: Every proof of $\forall x\forall y( x\cdot Sy = x\cdot y + x )$ in PA must at some point prove $\forall x\forall y( x\cdot Sy = x\cdot y + x )$ directly -- because that is the only way the proof can depend on that axiom, as it must.

Comment: (+1) I've heard that there is a theory of topology of proofs - this must be an illustration of what zero-dimensional looks like!

Comment: But this can be proven by contradiction.  First assume that your axiom is wrong, but since it contradicts the axiom, it must be true by contradiction.  I note that this has a similar structure to the argument I wish to avoid, but in this case I'm using the axiom rather than the "direct proof" in my contradiction which is permitted.

Comment: @Kenshin: That's exactly the reasoning you say in your question you want to **exclude**.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, not quite, I wish to avoid relying on the proof.  If it so happens an axiom is the same as it's proof, I can use the axiom.  I can edit the question for clarity in this regard.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, otherwise I couldn't use any axiom, as one could argue that all axioms are proofs (trivially).  I wish to allow axioms in the proof by contradiction, just not direct proofs.

Comment: @Kenshin: If you want to ask a different question than the one you have asked here, _ask it as a new question_ rather than moving the goalposts on the one you have already asked and gotten an answer to.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, no problem, happy to do that also :)

Comment: @Kenshin: And when you do so, be sure to provide an explicit definition of your (apparently extremely nonstandard) concept of "direct proof".

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I think you have misinterpreted my comments.  My definition of direct proof is standard, it is my restrictions on what I wish to allow in the proof by contradiction that I want to adjust.

Comment: @Kenshin: It sure sounds like you are using a concept of "direct proof" according to which pointing out that such-and-such is an axiom does NOT constitute a "direct proof". Such a concept is necessarily non-standard, because in any remotely sane and standard way of using the words, pointing to an axiom is the _most direct way one can conceivably prove anything_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, you have misinterpreted because I agree with you that an axiom is a trivial direct proof.  It is the restriction I want to adjust in my proof by contradiction, because I will allow axioms (i.e. trivial direct proofs) to be used in the proof by contradiction.

Comment: @Kenshin: Let me quote you: "I wish to allow axioms in the proof by contradiction, just not direct proofs." If you disallow direct proofs everywhere in the proof tree and you agree with the standard meaning of "direct proof", then you're necessarily also disallowing axioms, because mentioning an axiom constitutes a direct proof.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, we can both read the comments, my comment there could have been clearer, but nevertheless, I think we both realise at this point we're in agreement.

Comment: @Kenshin: We are not in agreement if you think you can disallow subproofs that are (according to the standard meaning) direct proofs without also disallowing every use of an axiom.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I accepted your answer didn't I?  I therefore do allow all direct proofs here.  The new question will be subtly different, with new conditions as requested.

Comment: @Kenshin: I'm talking about the revised question you say you're going to ask. The one where you want to disallow direct proofs but allow axioms.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, but cannot I constrain the question to only allow direct proofs to be used in the proof by contradiction where those direct proofs are axioms, or derivations using proof by contradiction from those axioms.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, perhaps this will clarify:  Suppose all direct proofs are deemed invalid, yet axioms are valid.  In this case, while axioms constitute direct proofs, they also exist independently as axioms.  So it is wrong to prove the axiom from itself in this scenario, but it isn't wrong to prove the axiom using contradiction trivially.  This will be the set up of the new question.

Comment: @Kenshin: Sure. (But it would be easiler to describe that as "the only allowed inference rules are proof-by-contradiction and axioms", and not mention direct proofs at all).

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes I agree with you