# Can axioms be proven?

Tags: logic, axioms

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2880196/can-all-proven-theorems-be-proven-by-contradiction/2880217#2880217) answer by Henning Makholm, he states that the following statement can be proven in Peano Arithmetic:
$$
\forall x:\forall y:x\cdot S(y)=(x\cdot y)+x \, .
$$

> The proof is very simple—since the claim to be proved is one of the axioms of PA, simply stating it with "(axiom)" next to it constitutes a proof.

My question is: which logic inference rule(s) tell us that an axiom constitutes a proof of itself?

Comment: A proof of $X$ is a finite sequence of well-formed sentences (well-formed formulas with no free variables) in the language of the theory such that each sentence is either an axiom, a tautology, or a consequence of previous sentences using a valid rule of inference, and where the final sentence in the sequence is $X$. A proof of an axiom consists of a one-sentence proof listing the axiom.

Comment: The answer depends on what logical system you are using, but all sane logical systems have the property that the axioms are provable. In natural deduction, the proofs of the axioms are the proof trees with exactly one node.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thank you; that my answers my question. You can convert your comment to an answer, if you wish.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin So there's no such thing as a formal system that allows formulas with free variables?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Of course, there is, as you know. Plenty of details to be filled out.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I was just curious why you specified "sentence" instead of "wff" in your definition...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Most formal systems that are in use have a "universal generalization" rule that means that the wffs with free variables can be replaced with sentence in which all the free variables are universally quantified.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Of course in such a system evidently there _are_ free variables in proofs, or the universal gemeralization rule would be useless. if anything such systems seem like counterexamples to the idea that the definition of proof should specify sentences - these systems are precisely why that word bothered me...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Fair enough; too late to edit a comment, though.

Comment: In a theory with axioms (like Peano arithmetic) the axioms are the starting points and they are not proved. They can be proved in some "more general" theory.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Your comment seems to contradict Arturo's comment above.

Comment: Axioms are never "proven" (nor can they be, ultimately), so one says that the axiom is simply "given", not "proven".

Comment: @Marcos: In the context of logic, the axioms of a certain formal system certainly are provable. See Arturo's comment above.

Comment: @Joe:  No.  If they are provable they are theorems or "valid conclusions".  In the context of logic, you might have an axiom of "identity" that says "True is true.".  This cannot be proven but you probably will want to keep it axiomatically.

Comment: @Marcos: In any first-order theory, the axioms are theorems of the theory – simply stating the axiom amounts to proving it. Note that in formal logic, the term “proof” has a precise technical meaning. All of this is explained in Arturo’s comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Arturo mentions in the comments, we actually don't need to use any inference rules to conclude that stating an axiom amounts to proving it. It is immediate from the definition of "proof" in predicate calculus:

> A proof of $X$ is a finite sequence of well-formed sentences
> (well-formed formulas with no free variables) in the language of the
> theory such that each sentence is either an axiom, a tautology, or a
> consequence of previous sentences using a valid rule of inference, and
> where the final sentence in the sequence is $X$. A proof of an axiom
> consists of a one-sentence proof listing the axiom.

(Actually, as David C. Ullrich also points out in the comments, in most deductive systems, we don't need proofs to consists of well-formed *sentences*: we merely need each line to be a well-formed formula; however, this is a technical point that is irrelevant to the issue at hand.)